# wkhtmltopdf : How do I increase the PDF quality of a document generated?

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am generating pdf using wkhtmltopdf. The text/image quality rendered in the document is not  to the expected quality. Images look blurred and text does look sharp. Is there any way I can do to increase the quality?

Comment: This is a very broad question :) Can you show us an example of what is wrong and what is expected, that would help quite a bit! Also, what version are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try giving this thread a read http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=379

Especially the part  in comment #15 about disabling smart resizing applies.

Add the command line option `--disable-smart-shrinking`.

Comment: @Serge,  I am not able to implement this, c# wrapper throws exception. My arguments are as 
`p.StartInfo.Arguments = " --disable-smart-shrinking --margin-left 0mm --margin-right 0mm --margin-top 27mm --margin-bottom 12mm --footer-html customFooter.html --header-html customHeader.html " + urlsSeparatedBySpaces + " " + outputFilename;`